# Merging an entire Object3D/Mesh hierarchy together

Tags: javascript, merge, geometry, three.js, hierarchy

I am working on a project that is dynamically generating trees. It's currently only in an early prototype stages, and so the branches and leaves are just simple cubes. The tree is made up of a hierarchy of the cubes, nested with the rotations and scaling down of the branches. I need to be able to add more branches/leaves to the tree, but can convert it to a static tree just for rendering purposes.

I am running into a problem when the tree gets too large, rendering many cubes slowing the program down.

After doing a lot of research, I discovered the THREE.GeometryUtils.merge() function, that would merge all the branches in my tree into one object that can be rendered/transformed much faster than before. However the problem I am encountering is the merge doesn't take into account all of the parent transforms, merging only it's vertices.

The basic code I am trying to get working is as follows. I have played around with applying the matrix to the geometry and a few other things, but have not got anything working properly yet.

```
var newGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
var newTree = tree.clone(); //Clones the tree so the original does not get altered
newTree.traverse(function(child){
    if(child.parent){
        child.applyMatrix( child.parent.matrixWorld);
    }
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(newGeo, child);
});
```

I have created a simple jsFiddle program for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/JeYhF/2/
The left object is 4 meshes parented inside each other and the right object is the mesh combination. As you can see, each component of the combination has its own transforms applied (translation in y axis by 11 units and rotation in z axis by PI/4), but they are not affected by the parent transforms.
The function in question is the MergeTree() function. This program would only work in chrome for me.

Any advice for how to solve this problem would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the matrix world was not calculated before the merging. So the transforms were all just the identity matrix.

```
newTree.traverse(function(child){
    if(child.parent){
        child.updateMatrixWorld();
        child.applyMatrix(child.parent.matrixWorld);    
    }
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(newGeo, child);
});
```